# How writte this for working onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple questión, but i don´t understand how writte

```
$wish_1='<span onclick=alert("Register or Login Now");></span>';
```

The case it´s i can´t put spaces because not working and if put ' no works i try also

```
onclick=\""\;
```

But don´t fix the probem

Sure it´s super easy question, but at the moment i can´t find nothing at this, and need fixed , because i try  all and sure it´s bad written

When click over tag span, never receive any alert in javascript or something more

Regards community, thank´s

Comment: replace your containing quotes and add quotes for the onclick: `$wish_1=\`<span onclick="alert('Register or Login Now');"></span>\`;`

Comment: that give me error in syntax by this '

Comment: I don't understand your comment. can you share the error? I just ran this in **this page's dev tools console** and everything worked fine

Comment: If you use this <span onclick="alert('Register or Login Now');">u</span>, works but in my example this it´s inside string y copy this code $wish_1=`<span onclick="alert('Register or Login Now');"></span>`; and run with print $wish_1; onclick don´t show nothing

Comment: don't use inline js / css - it's bad practice that leads to hard-to maintain code

Comment: maybe you need to add more information to your question. I can't find a reason why changing the outer quotes into ticks should break everything here and I'm not sure I understand your comments. you have 3 types of quotes for javascript: `"`, `'`, `\``. that should be enough in your case

Answer (score 2):

There you go:

I **escaped the value** of the `onclick` attribute with `\`. This should work!

```js
var $wish_1 = "<span onclick=\"alert('Register or Login Now');\">Click me!</span>";

$('body').html($wish_1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```